# Integration of two sites (one is Drupal-based, the other isn't)

Tags: authentication-authorization

I'm trying to integrate two sites (one is Drupal-based, and the other isn't), and I need [single sign-on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on). How can I realize it?

I have sites on different domains.

Comment: Has the non-drupal website got his own users?

Comment: Can the non-Drupal site be configured to use Apache basic authentication?  I have some code I have been meaning to publish using mod_auth_mysql and mod_auth_cookie that does SSO using Drupal's user table with any basic-authentication site.  Needs updating for D7.  I could make an answer out of this if it sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do your authentication externally to Drupal, you could use the [Secure Site](http://drupal.org/project/securesite) module.  You'd still need mod_auth_cookie to avoid double-password entry, but at least the username and password would be the same.  I don't see mod_auth_cookie anywhere out on the internet any more, but I've got the code and could re-publish. As I mentioned in my comment above, it needs a little work.

Another way to avoid double password entry would be to put your sites at example.com/drupal and example.com/other, and protect all of example.com with Apache basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

When the non-Drupal site has a user created, use Drupal bootstrapping to create a new Drupal user. You can also use it to authenticate the user on the non-Drupal site.

It'd also be fairly trivial to write a script to generate Drupal users from the non-Drupal site, assuming you know their passwords. If not, send out a "forgot password" email to the users created in the Drupal site.

Check the documention for `drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL)`.

Last I did this I had some issues and found that this helped:

```
chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, setting up a Single-Sign On scenario involves the core user.module. There is an example on [api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_external_login_register/7) that explains how to do this.